# Wait observable inside another observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm having a problem where I'm returning an observable and sometimes inside that observable I should get a value from another observable. I simplified my problem to much simpler case but main problem is still there. Consider following code that works:

```js
    public dummyStream(): Observable<number> {
    return of(true).pipe(
      switchMap(isTrue =>
        iif(() => isTrue === true,
          combineLatest([of([1,2,3,4,5]), of(2)]).pipe(
            map(([arrayOfNumbers, multiplier]) => {
              const results = arrayOfNumbers.map(num => {
                if (num !== 5) return num;
                else return 4;
              });
      
              return results.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
            })
          ),
          
          combineLatest([of([1,2,3,4,5]), of(2)]).pipe(
            map(([arrayOfNumbers, multiplier]) => {
              return 0;
            })
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

So little explanation. It all starts with `of(true)`. For simplicity in this example it's always true so once we get to `iif()` condition is always true.

Inside there I have `combineLatest` that combines two observables. Then eventually I do `arrayOfNumbers.map` and simply return that number again except in a case where number is 5 then I return 4.

Now what I'd like to do is to return `of(num * multiplier)` but then of course return type from `map` would by either `number` or `Observable<number>` and that's not working.

So this is same code but instead of returning number I'm returning `Observable<number>` in else block

```js
    public dummyStream(): Observable<number> {
    return of(true).pipe(
      switchMap(isTrue =>
        iif(() => isTrue === true,
          combineLatest([of([1,2,3,4,5]), of(2)]).pipe(
            map(([arrayOfNumbers, multiplier]) => {
              const results = arrayOfNumbers.map(num => {
                if (num !== 5) return num;
                else of(num * multiplier);
              });
      
              return results.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
            })
          ),
          
          combineLatest([of([1,2,3,4,5]), of(2)]).pipe(
            map(([arrayOfNumbers, multiplier]) => {
              return 0;
            })
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

Now how should I change this so that `dummyStream()` return type would still be `Observable<number>` but so that inside my else block I'm using another observable?

Comment: You don't need `of`, just do `return num * multiplier`.  Inside the `map`, you don't want to return `Observable`, you are modifying the emission, so just return the plain value.

Comment: In a real world case I definitely need to use observable at some point because I don't have a plain value at that point. Using of(num * multiplier) is just an example here to keep things simple.

Comment: oh, I see, then you need to use a Higher Order Mapping Operator, like `switchMap` instead of your plain `map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would restructure `dummyStream` like this:

```
function dummyStream() {
    return of(true).pipe(
      switchMap(isTrue =>
        iif(() => isTrue === true,
          combineLatest([of([1,2,3,4,5]), of(2)]).pipe(
            switchMap(([arrayOfNumbers, multiplier]) => {
              return forkJoin(arrayOfNumbers.map(num => {
                if (num !== 5) return of(num);
                else return of(num * multiplier);
              }));
            }),
            map((results) => results.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0))
          ),
          
          combineLatest([of([1,2,3,4,5]), of(2)]).pipe(
            map(([arrayOfNumbers, multiplier]) => {
              return 0;
            })
          )
        )
      )
    );
}
```

So instead of just return `num` in the map, you return `of(num)` so that you end up with an array of `Observable<number>`. Change the outer `map` to a `switchMap` and wrap the resulting array in a `forkJoin` to wait for all inner observables to finish. You can put the `reduce` in its own `map` afterwards.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=2&pln=4&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgeQEYGcCmUBuBDVAG0wBo50B3YGAYwAsBZPMM4YAMzIk7hohFTAAdpgAyeGJnQwyIZmXbQA1gCkIwuAF847KPzgAiKAA8AVugMBYAFA2b7AK5CaMYBCFwAJg5AgAngDKMFCYeCAAFACUiDZwcXAhMA5QHtzhwQ6YkQB0YMBgmOGx8XGU1PRMYOHA6AAqUJlwALwAfMUlcWzs4VHNLXA19Y1NI3AZpO0dcXwCwmISUjDhANppywCMJABMJADMJAAsJACsALqRXN1bkee5%20YWTU6VUtIzMPct4UFB4fsjsADkfKhsOhZA5CK4wIRgNhzn0YtYnk9EskPIooKp1EJwl8fn9AcDQdk5FUhD4EQhHsj4hw4OFySA4ABCUbHaKolJwNKMyIAbmpNLgmEIWASmCSXJ5FIAVHAQBCoTDsPzBU9NJFVUihVoLmqSqSeiF0Ir0NFWuKTZD0NkQt4aIVwmAQjgyDRklBzf1nZgcHAANS8D1kAAMmv1cD12uREZmghE4kk0hWa02O32RzOF25VxuOTyBSK0ZphpWeN%20-yBAlB4Mh%20WVUHhFqpxaFnI8IYFrfVkQjve7cX7UyH8S1miAA)

Comment: Thanks! This was definitely what I was looking for! I don't know why after all these years I'm still pretty lost sometimes with RxJS. Anyway, now I just need to apply this to my real problem. After all it's more or less the same, just much bigger spaghetti :D

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
const data1$ = of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).pipe(concatAll());
// const data1$ = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const data2$ = of(2).pipe(repeat());

const source$ = zip(data1$, data2$).pipe(
  map(([num, multiplier]) => num !== 5 ? num : num * multiplier),
  reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0),
);

source$.subscribe(console.log);
const falseResult$ = of(0);
iif(() => true, source$, falseResult$).subscribe(console.log);
```